# Logic for "Erase SVG Stroke"?

Tags: svg, curve, polyline

## Problem

Hi,

So I have noticed that software like Microsoft Edge and OneNote and Notability, store hand drawn strokes as vector curves or lines. They also provide the ability to *erase* strokes, by dragging the eraser over them.

I wanted to implement something similar in my software, an SVG Animation and Creation bundle, and I have come up with the logic for the freehand stroke to SVG curve, a demo is available here:
https://phantomzback.github.io/SvgFreehandDrawDemo/polylineTest.html

It uses the `polyline` tag with the cursor positions, and path simplification is something I also plan to implement. But before that, I need a way to detect if the eraser has gone *over* the stroke. I have an approach but I am not sure how great of an approach it is. I'd appreciate advice on how this can be improved or alternative methods to tackle the problem.

## Current Idea

Find the pixels where the stroke is rendered, and save it in an array. Then, check for if the eraser tool is active and goes over that stroke. If it does, delete this stroke.

Finding the pixels shouldn't be very hard since a polyline is a bunch of points and lines drawn between them. But I plan on adding support for paths later, for which a better approach might be needed.

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would rather use [canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/canvas) for this

Comment: @enxaneta the application is not a web app or an electron application. It's core will be implemented in Qt, and will use pure C/C++ for the logic.